# Why cannot I view runtime errors on Application Insights?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

I'm working on a Web API 2 project (.NET Full Framework 4.6.1) with Owin and Application Insights 2.7.2 version.

I have one controller with a action like following:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Prova")]
public void Prova()
{
    throw new Exception("Questa è l'eccezione.");
}
```

When I call this action I cannot view exception in Application Insights:

[image: Application Insights logs]

Microsoft declare that, from Application Insights > SDK 2.6, action's not managed runtime exceptions are intercepted automatically ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions#web-api)).

Why I cannot view my runtime exceptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions#web-api), for web api:

```
Unhandled exceptions originating from controllers typically result in 500 "Internal Server Error" response.
```

I also tested it at my side, for the unhandled exceptions from controller, it results in 500 error as the doc said.

My code in controller:

```
  public string Get(int id)
        {
            throw new Exception("a set");

        }
```

And the result as below:
[image]